# mongoose integration problem ( aka insertMany )

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I stuck in the middle of a process because i couldn't remove the iron curtain behind my flaw. I created a db via mongoose and as everyone else i was expecting to see my db when i wrote down show dbs yet i couldn't find a way. also when i try to write down `.save()` i get errors. All helps will be appreciated. Thank you.

```
    // jshint esversion:6

const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const app = express();

let items = [];
let workItems = [];


app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.use(express.static("public"));

mongoose.connect = ('mongodb://localhost:27017/todosDB', {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
});

const itemsSchema = {
    name: String
};

const Item = mongoose.model("Item", itemsSchema)

const item1 = new Item({
    name: "Welcome toDo List"
});

const item2 = new Item({
    name: "Press + to add"
});

const item3 = new Item({
    name: "Press - to delete"
});

const defaultItems = [item1, item2, item3];



Item.insertMany(defaultItems, function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log("Verileri başarıyla kaydedildi")
    }
});



app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render("lists", {
        listTitle: "Today",
        newItems: items
    });
});

app.post("/", function (req, res) {

    item = req.body.newItem;

    items.push(item);

    res.redirect("/");

});


app.get("/work", function (req, res) {
    res.render("list", {
        listTitle: "Work List",
        newListItems: workItems
    });
});

app.get("/about", function (req, res) {
    res.render("about");

});

app.post("/work", function (req, res) {

    let item = req.body.newItem;
    workItems.push(item);
    res.redirect("/work");

});

app.listen(3000, function () {

    console.log("Server Çevrimiçi");

});
```

Comment: "when i try to write down `.save()` i get errors", what's the error you got?

Comment: thammada i get `defaultItems.save is not a function` @thammada

Comment: That's because it's just an array you have to use `.save` in the individual items. And what about `Item.insertMany`, any errors?

Comment: i don't get any error actually there is no output in `Item.insertMany` on shell :/ no console.log output @thammada

Comment: I think `itemsSchema` should be a mongoose schema instance `const itemsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({ name: String })`

Comment: i did it beforehand but i get `new Item is not identified` error @thammada

Comment: That's not an actual node.js error, please try with `new mongoose.Schema` again and include the actual error

Comment: sorry i did it but there is no output. same vicious cycle :( @thammada

Comment: found the solutions just deleted `let items = []; let workItems = [];` and worked